# Trouble with Check Boxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, conditional-statements

ive created a series of checkboxes for companies and employees.  Id like for when the company is selected, all the users get checked.  My issue is with the conditional - whenever i click the checkbox the code runs, whether its checked or not.  Obviously, id only like it to sun when the check box gets checked, and not when it is unchecked. i THINK that "this" refers to the checkbox the "onClick" event is set in. Thanks.

```
function checkCompAll(comp) {
    // if the the company checkbox is selected...
if (this.checked=true){
    // query all inputs and select only check boxes with the name "userlogrestrict" and this companies id number in them.  Return an array
    // named "checkboxes"
    var thiscompusers = "userlogrestrict_"+comp;
    var checkboxes = new Array();
    var elems = document.newlog.elements;
    var len = elems.length;

    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {

        if (elems[i].type === 'checkbox') {
            var thischeckbox = elems[i].name.split("_");
                if ((thischeckbox[0] == "userlogrestrict")&&(thischeckbox[1] == comp)){
                    checkboxes.push(elems[i]);
                }

        }
    }

    console.log(checkboxes);

} // end the if
```

}

Thanks for the help.  Yes, the = vs == was an issue and assigning the checkbox as true.  Another issue was i dont know if the function was clear on what "this" was.  I added "this" to the function call - which told the function what the name of the checkbox was - now it works.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: In the if condition, you are using = instead of ==

Comment: *"i THINK that "this" refers to the checkbox the "onClick" event is set in"* Depends on how you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition, you are using `=` instead of `==`

= is an assignment operator, its used only for assigning some value

```
  if (this.checked==true){
```

Once you fix that it will work